# TabBar embedded NavigationController bar disappears when segue to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController which is connected to 3 UINavigationControllers. Each of these have a UIViewController as a root view controller. When I click on a button in one of these ViewControllers (VC1), I want it to segue to new ViewController (VC2). Simple enough.

During runtime, when the segue takes place and VC2 appears, the navigation bar disappears.

The navigation bar is present in the storyBoard / interface builder, and the segue is the type: present (Push).

Code in VC1:

```
@IBAction func create_clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

It might help to know how the UITabBarController *tabBar* is instantiated:

```
func login() {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryBoard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBar = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar")

    window?.rootViewController = tabBar
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What type of segue are you using?

Comment: Present (Push) segue

Comment: Does the navigation bar show in the Storyboard for VC2?

Comment: Yes: the navigation bar does show in the Storyboard for VC2

Comment: "present (Push)" That's meaningless. `present` and `push` are _opposites_. Which is it????

Comment: Apologies, it's "show (push)"

Comment: "VC2 doesn't even have a navigationController at ViewDidLoad()" That is normal.

Comment: Hmm. Whether the navigation bar appears is up to the individual view controller. Any chance you've configured this view controller to hide the navigation bar?

Comment: On the contrary: the only code I've written in VC2 to do with the navigation controller is: *self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)*

Comment: :) Put that code in VC2's `viewDidAppear` and also print `self.navigationController` to the console to see whether we truly lack a navigation controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159858/discussion-between-legatro-and-matt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a great deal of experimentation, we determined that even though Interface Builder *said* this was a Show (Push) segue, and even though we were in a Navigation Controller to start with,
 it was behaving as a Present Modally segue.

So we changed the segue type, using the pop-up menu in Interface Builder, from Show (Push) to plain Push, even though that's deprecated — and the interface worked correctly.

And then we changed it back to Show (Push) and the interface continued to work correctly. Problem solved!

I suspect the storyboard was corrupted in some way. Obviously Interface Builder should not lie to you about what kind of segue this is, but basically, that is what it seems to have been doing.

**EDIT** The problem was caused, apparently, by making a Show Detail segue and changing it to Show. When you do that, it's still a Show Detail segue, which in this context behaves as a modal presentation. That's an Xcode bug! I reported it, and Apple now says this will be fixed in Xcode 9.3.

Comment: @vacawama And we did it just like Sherlock Holmes. We eliminated every other possibility and were left with the conclusion that, despite all appearances, this wasn’t a Push segue at all. I had no idea that was possible!

Comment: It would be an interesting experiment to start with the original project and view the Storyboard as source and compare that to the storyboard file after the change to Push and back to Show(Push).

Comment: @vacawama Before: `<segue destination="tqh-u7-1Yx" kind="show" identifier="S_home-createGroup" action="showDetailViewController:sender:" id="5pZ-1W-mSH"/>` After: `<segue destination="tqh-u7-1Yx" kind="show" identifier="S_home-createGroup" id="5pZ-1W-mSH"/>` Note the spurious action.

Comment: @vacawama I'll tell you how! That's what happens if you initially make your segue a Show Detail segue and then change it to a Show segue. I just tried it in a plain vanilla project. — So now it's labeled Show but it still acts like Show Detail — and out of its correct context, a Show Detail segue will fall back on behaving like Present.

Comment: I reported this as a bug, and according to Apple it is fixed in Xcode 9.3: "Changing a segue from “Show Detail” to “Show” no longer keeps the action selector for Show Detail... (23505175)"

Comment: Thanks @matt for closing the loop!

Comment: Many thanks!!! in fact 9.3 does not finally fix it. I'm working on a project, updated to 9.3 and suddenly the segues "show detail" acted like "push" ... nothing helped until I found this post. Changed the segue to (deprecated) "push" and changed back to "show detail" and now everything works fine again ..